# Перевыделение памяти

Tags: c++

Делаю программу считывания с файла слов. Заранее не знаю сколько слов будет в файле, по этому нужен динамический массив, который будет увеличивать свою вместимость по мере считывания. В С есть функция realloc, которая позволяет это делать без проблем. Как такое реализовать в С++? И можно ли смешивать оператор new вместе с realloc? Насколько это будет правильно работать?

Comment: В чем проблема использовать `std::vector`?

Comment: ...вместе с `std::string`.

Comment: Можно подробнее пожалуйста?
vector<string> str;, так?

Comment: std::vector - это массив с динамическим размером. Не нужно придумывать велосипед, найдите пример его использования и примените у себя.

Comment: @W0lfEnd ага: `vector<string> words;`. Добавление элемента в вектор: `words.push_back("hello");`.

Comment: на самом деле вектор будет хуже по производительности чем realloc. Причина в том что вектор при добавлении создает новый кусок памяти и копирует туда свои елементы. А realloc увеличивает сущеествющию(без копирования)

Comment: @AndrioSkur `realloc` не настолько всемогущ, как Вам кажется: "*The `realloc` function **deallocates** the old object pointed to by `ptr` and returns a pointer to a new object...*"

Comment: @alexolut, насколько я могу судить после беглого ознакомления с кодом glibc, запрос у функции realloc увеличения выделенной области не приводит к копированию блока данных, если в куче в списке за этим блоком есть свободное место. Происходит просто увеличение зарезервированной области.

Comment: @mymedia некоторые оптимизации безусловно возможны, но это не гарантируется стандартом.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В Си и Си++ существенно различаются подходы к управлению памятью. В частности, вам не нужно вручную беспокоиться и последовательно выделять память для растущего массива. Это уже умеет библиотечный шаблонный класс [`std::vector`](http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) — этакий динамический массив.

Ваша задача чтения слов из файла решается в две строчки: открытие файла и собственно чтение, которое производится с помощью итераторов (а-ля указатели).

```
ifstream f("слова.txt");
vector<string> words((istream_iterator<string>(f)), istream_iterator<string>());
```

Если первый аргумент конструктора `std::vector` не взять в скобки, вся строчка будет интерпретирована как объявление функции, а не объекта.

Использование:

```
cout << "Вот первое слово: " << words[0];
cout << "Всего прочитано слов: " << words.size();
```

А благодаря автоматическому вызову деструктора при достижении конца блока, в котором объявлен вектор, память освобождается сама. Дополнительно ничего писать не надо.

Comment: Еще мне нужно получить доступ к каждой букве из каждого стринга, подскажите, как правильно обратится к ним?
words[i]... что дальше?

Comment: `words[i][j]` — j-ая буква i-ого слова

Comment: Начиная с c++11 можно использовать фигурные скобки: `vector<string> words{istream_iterator<string>(f), {}};`.